# Numbers on the launcher

Tags: launcher

Using 12.04 LTS - few days ago, I left my machine on while I went out. On my return, the launcher was showing (it is set to be hidden) and there were small numbers 1-9 on the icons and letters s on the bottom-most icon and t on the rubbish bin. System still worked fine, although the launcher remained visible, and would not hide. After about 20 mins work, they suddenly vanished and the launcher hid itself.. is this a normal action ? It hasn't happened since..

Comment: The numbers may be found by pressing down the super-key (Windows-key/CMD) and is used to launch applications by pressing "Super-key+number" (eg, super+1 might launch/switch to Firefox if Firefox is the top application on the launcher)

However - I assume you found a bug to invoke that behaviour since you said you worked for 20 minutes, and I hardly think you would have had the super-key accidentally pressed down without noticing for 20 minutes ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly normal - those are the numbers you press with the Super button to open the corresponding app.

But it staying for 20 minutes - I guess it is a bug. But nothing serious, so you shouldn't worry unless it repeats.